# How can I loop through this dictionary instead of hardcoding the keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, cs50

So far, I have this code (from cs50/pset6/DNA):

```
import csv

data_dict = {}
with open(argv[1]) as data_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    for record in reader:
        # `record` is a dictionary of column-name & value
        name = record["name"]
        data = {
            "AGATC": record["AGATC"],
            "AATG": record["AATG"],
            "TATC": record["TATC"],
        }

        data_dict[name] = data

print(data_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'Alice': {'AATG': '8', 'AGATC': '2', 'TATC': '3'},
     'Bob': {'AATG': '1', 'AGATC': '4', 'TATC': '5'},
 'Charlie': {'AATG': '2', 'AGATC': '3', 'TATC': '5'}}
```

Here is the csv file:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

But my goal is to achieve the exact same thing, but instead of hardcoding the keys `AATG`, etc., and also because I'll use a much much bigger database that contains more values, I want to be able to loop through the data, instead of doing this:

```
data = {
            "AGATC": record["AGATC"],
            "AATG": record["AATG"],
            "TATC": record["TATC"],
        }
```

Could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want the `data` to contain everything that `record` (which is already a dictionary) does *except* for the `'name'` entry, correct?

Comment: No, I want to have a dictionary that contains dictionaries, exactly like this: `{'Alice': {'AATG': '8', 'AGATC': '2', 'TATC': '3'},
     'Bob': {'AATG': '1', 'AGATC': '4', 'TATC': '5'},
 'Charlie': {'AATG': '2', 'AGATC': '3', 'TATC': '5'}}` However I want to loop through the dictionary not hardcode what I want it to say of each individual sub-dictionary. Do you understand @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using pandas.

Using your example data as .csv file:

```
pandas.read_csv('example.csv', index_col = 0).transpose().to_dict()
```

Outputs:

```
{'Alice': {'AGATC': 2, 'AATG': 8, 'TATC': 3},
 'Bob': {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5},
 'Charlie': {'AGATC': 3, 'AATG': 2, 'TATC': 5}}
```

`index_col = 0` because you have names column which I set as index (so that later becomes top level keys in dictionary)

`.transpose()` so top level keys are names and not features (AGATC, AATG, etc.)

`.to_dict()` to transform pandas.DataFrame to python dictionary

Comment: Wow! Thanks, very simple! But is panda a module or is it from python3 already? Thanks @dm2!

Comment: It is an external module which you need to first install via pip, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through a dictionary in python simply enough like this:

```py
for key in dictionary:
  print(key, dictionary[key])
```

Comment: Hey, but will this convert the csv file into an organized dictionary. Because I'll later have to access these values and compare them...

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `pandas`:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {}
with open(argv[1]) as data_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
    df = df.set_index('name') # set name column as index
    data_dict = df.transpose().to_dict() # transpose to make dict with indexes
   
print(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track using csv.DictReader.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

data_dict = {}

with open('fasta.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for record in reader:
        name = record.pop('name')
        data_dict[name] = record

pprint(data_dict)
```

Prints

```
{'Alice': {'AATG': '8', 'AGATC': '2', 'TATC': '3'},
 'Bob': {'AATG': '1', 'AGATC': '4', 'TATC': '5'},
 'Charlie': {'AATG': '2', 'AGATC': '3', 'TATC': '5'}}
```

Comment: Hey @ChrisCharley! Could you please explain to me with more detail what each line is doing? I would appreciate it!!